# Adjusting y axis origin for stacked geom_bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot stacked bar plot with ggplot2 and am having difficulty getting the colour mapping and stack order right.  The following example has been developed from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13423600/1156245) to achieve a non-zero y-axis origin, but as you can see it creates other problems.  The colours don't map properly and the plot order is wrong.  Grateful for any pointers on the best way to handle this.  The desired output should scale colours as per the factor levels for `rating`, with colours in the order specified.

```
require(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(grp = rep(c('A','B'), each = 4), 
               rating = rep(c('bad','poor','ok','good'), 2),
               value = c(15,45,35,5,5,15,55,30), stringsAsFactors = F)

if(require(reshape2)) reshape2::dcast(d, grp ~ rating) # show structure

d$rating = ordered(d$rating, levels=c('bad','poor','ok','good'))
d$grp = ordered(d$grp, levels=c('B','A'))

# split datsets so we can plot 'negative' bars
d1 = subset(d, rating %in% c('ok','good'))
d2 = subset(d, rating %in% c('poor','bad'))

ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data = d1, aes(x=grp, y=value, fill=rating), stat='identity', position='stack') + 
  geom_bar(data = d2, aes(x=grp, y=-value, fill=rating), stat='identity', position='stack') + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','pink','lightgreen','green')) +
  geom_line(data=d1, aes(x=c(.5,2.5), y=c(0,0)), size=2, linetype='dashed') +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a bit of reordering and using limits() will help:

```
d2 <- d2[order(d2$rating, decreasing =T),]

ggplot() + 
     geom_bar(data = d1, aes(x=grp, y=value, fill=rating), stat='identity',
               position='stack') + 
     geom_bar(data = d2, aes(x=grp, y=-value, fill=rating), stat='identity', 
               position='stack') + 
     scale_fill_manual(values=c('red','pink','lightgreen','green'),
                       limits=c("bad","poor","ok","good"))+
     geom_line(data=d1, aes(x=c(.5,2.5), y=c(0,0)), size=2, linetype='dashed') +
     coord_flip()
```

[image]

For anyone who wishes to learn ggplot2, I strongly recommend getting the Winston Chang's [R Graphics Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449316956).

Comment: Many thanks Serban. So am I right to understand that ranking by factor levels isn't implemented for graphical sub-elements?  Bit surprising that ggplot doesn't map colour to factor levels automatically.

Comment: I see. Use reroder() or see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331892/order-and-color-of-bars-in-ggplot2-barplot?rq=1

Comment: Handy tip. Yes we clearly have working options which is good.